# Is there a way to check when an ssh key from authorized_keys was last used?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, logs, sshd, key-authentication

My authorized_keys on some of my debian flavoured servers have become bloated with keys from old PCs, etc. Is there a way I can tell which key has been used to log in? I would like to clean it up.
I have searched through /var/log/auth with no real luck.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Debian flavours: Debian/Ubuntu/Raspian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The teachable part of this moment is perhaps that the "comment" field of an
SSH key is importantly useful.  While the default value of `user@hostname` is
reasonable, it is very common for one user to create multiple SSH keys, each
for a different purpose:

```
ssh-keygen -C "this key is for backups" -t ....
ssh-keygen -C "webmaster access for www.example.com"
```

More importantly, when the public SSH key is inserted into
`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, it's good to retain (or even expand) that comment
to identify the key.  If the key has no comment, one can be edited in.
Without a unique key comment, it's difficult to differentiate one key from
another, since as you say, the SHA256 hash has no immediately obvious
correlation to the public key.

So:

- Use a unique comment (`-C "this is the comment"`) when you create SSH keys
- When adding keys to your authorized_keys file, make sure the comment
  reflects not only who the key belongs to, but also the reason why
  you're granting access to that key.

Remember that (careful) editing of the comment will not harm the integrity of
the key.  You can edit a generic comment of an existing public key (either yours or someone else's) and make it more meaningful to you or to the purpose at hand.

With all that said, your question seemed like an interesting challenge.  The
main limitations to doing what you want are:

- as above, having a human-readable descriptor for a particular key, so that
  a used or dis-used key can be referred to without ambiguity
- SSH logs are the source document for when an SSH key is used, and those
  logs generally aren't retained indefinitel, so it's only possible to tell
  which SSH keys have been used "recently".  Even with long-term log retention, the year entry often isn't available in the log files, and sorting of alphabetic month names requires further rigmarole. This script takes the shortcut of simply counting the number of occurrences of a given key in each log file where it is found.
- SSH logs are usually read-protected from normal users, so it is likely
  that `sudo` access will be necessary to read them.

But let's proceed anyway!

It's likely that the list of public keys you want to check for "inactivity" are
the keys in your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.  This script expects a pathname
to such a file in a format acceptable to `ssh` and friends.  In particular, `ssh-keygen` will be used to read public keys and extract the SHA256 hash of
the underlying key, which is the hash that is needed to correlate to the
SSH logs in `/var/log/auth-log*`.

```
$ ssh-keygen -l -f .ssh/my-laptop-id_rsa.pub 
2048 SHA256:YmiLC7LFQ+mSE3SHkXzbpFuWi0HbIpGCaIUYuR6rAiM root@my-laptop (RSA)
```

We won't be referencing the first parameter (key length in bits), but the
second parameter is our all-important SHA256 hash of the key, and everything
beyond the second parameter is the key comment, plus the appended " (RSA)"
which reflects the cryptographic scheme used for the key.  `ssh-keygen -l` is
a major ally of this script, along with array techniques for storing multiple
keys -- one array for SHA256 hashes, another for each key's comment or
"label" as the script calls it.

Finally we iterate over the array of SHA256 hashes, `grep` through the
`/var/log/auth.log*` files to count how many times each one occurs, and
display the formatted results.

There's lots of room for improvement in this script, but hopefully this will
spark some ideas about the different ways there are to approach the problem,
as well as how to present the results.

```bash
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    
    set -e
    
    
    sha_of_pubkeys() {
    
    # Given an ssh authorized_keys file on stdin, extract the SHA256 hash of each
    # key, and return:
    #  (sha256 hash) <space> (key comment)
    # on stdout.
    
            grep '^[^#]' |
              ssh-keygen -l -f - |
              sed -Ee 's/^[^ ]* +//'
    
    } # sha_of_pubkeys
    
    
    count_sha_in_logs() {
    
    # Pass $1 with the key hash "SHA256:xxxxx"
    # We'll return stdout with "<tab>n time(s) in filename"
    
    regex="Accepted publickey for .* ssh2: .* $1$"
    grep -wc "$regex" /var/log/auth.log* |
      grep -v ':0$' |
      awk -F: '{printf "\t%8d time(s) in %s\n", $2, $1}'
    }
    
    
    ##############################
    #
    #       M A I N
    #
    ##############################
    
    
    [[ -r "$1" ]] || {
            printf "Can't read input file: %s\n" "$1"
            exit 1
    }
    
    # We'll identify pub keys by their (unique) comment field.
    # Store them in this array, indexed in order of occurrence.
    
    key_ids=()
    
    readarray -t key_ids << EOF
    $(
      # delete the first field (the hash) from sha_of_pubkeys stdout
      sha_of_pubkeys < "$1" |
        sed -Ee 's/^[^ ]* +//'
    )
    EOF
    
    # Store the SHA256 hash of each key in this array:
    
    key_shas=()
    
    readarray -t key_shas << EOF
    $(
      # the hash is the first field from sha_of_pubkeys
      sha_of_pubkeys < "$1" |
        awk '{print $1}'
    )
    EOF
    
    # How many unique keys did we find?
    
    n_ids=$(
    printf '%s\n' "${key_ids[@]}" |
      sort |
      uniq |
      wc -l
    )
    
    if ( [[ ${#key_shas[@]} -eq ${#key_ids[@]} ]] &&
         [[ ${#key_shas[@]} -eq ${n_ids} ]] )
    then
    
            printf '%d keys found in "%s".\nHere are their comment tags and key types:\n' ${n_ids} "$1"
    
            sha_count=()
            for i in $(jot $n_ids 0)
            do
                    printf '%4d ... %s\n' $(($i+1)) "${key_ids[$i]}"
                    sha_count+=( "$(count_sha_in_logs "${key_shas[$i]}")" )
            done
            printf '\n'
    
            for i in $(jot $n_ids 0)
            do
                    if [[ -z "${sha_count[$i]}" ]]
                    then
                            s='does not appear.'
                    else
                            s="$(printf 'appears:\n%s\n' "${sha_count[$i]}")"
                    fi
                    printf 'Key %d\n        label: "%s"\n   hash:  "%s"\n   %s\n\n' $(($i+1)) "${key_ids[$i]}" "${key_shas[$i]}" "$s"
            done
    
    else
    
            printf "Every key must have a comment field.\n"
            printf "Every comment field must be unique.\n"
            exit 1
    
    fi
```

Output:

```
$ sudo ./test.sh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
Password:
6 keys found in "/home/jim/.ssh/authorized_keys".
Here are their comment tags and key types:
   1 ... jim@w541 (RSA)
   2 ... admin@work-imac (RSA)
   3 ... admin@other-imac (RSA)
   4 ... jim@jimsdesk.example.com (RSA)
   5 ... jim@jimsdesk.example.com (ed25519) (ED25519)
   6 ... roland@bayou.remote.colleague.edu (RSA)

Key 1
        label: "jim@w541 (RSA)"
        hash:  "SHA256:CvsACdXgliEpeQtUriFW87vpMZEbO6V7znj/3bhmPwo"
        does not appear.

Key 2
        label: "admin@work-imac (RSA)"
        hash:  "SHA256:x9wjIdW1OpGQhQ6rGiN25Vm2Y8og7/6lajHDK8jJAM4"
        does not appear.

Key 3
        label: "admin@other-imac (RSA)"
        hash:  "SHA256:LJ1DTCnQ6UAoXhmF3+4RqEbzCwiS+rZ3P692a8c/nNE"
        does not appear.

Key 4
        label: "jim@jimsdesk.example.com (RSA)"
        hash:  "SHA256:cTQi5zMvfYegFAzffkWngraE8B1lJCagOxrS+TkwSaA"
        appears:
               4 time(s) in /var/log/auth.log.1

Key 5
        label: "jim@jimsdesk.example.com (ed25519) (ED25519)"
        hash:  "SHA256:sPvGf5/+N3OkYlS3JV53esv2ASn+GDusMSbStaHkmik"
        appears:
               1 time(s) in /var/log/auth.log

Key 6
        label: "roland@bayou.remote.colleague.edu (RSA)"
        hash:  "SHA256:58sSa6I24R+bsRgCMJ3v2Xog1G5bP7tP9o8V8dbVtec"
        does not appear.
```

Most of these keys have not been used recently.  Key 5 was used once today,
and Key 4 was used 4 times yesterday, assuming daily log
rotation of `/var/log/auth-log`.

Since we need `sudo` privs to read `/var/log/auth.log*` we might as well take a look at how often the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file is referenced:

```
$ sudo ./test.sh /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
8 keys found in "/root/.ssh/authorized_keys".
Here are their comment tags and key types:
   1 ... root@backup-host (RSA)
   2 ... ansible key (RSA)
   3 ... jim@jimsdesk (RSA)
   4 ... root@w541 (RSA)
   5 ... root@thumb (RSA)
   6 ... nagios@nagios-host (RSA)
   7 ... root@mrtg-host (RSA)
   8 ... jim@w541 (RSA)

Key 1
        label: "root@backup-host (RSA)"
        hash:  "SHA256:iHsBJAi3nZt3op/kuJLQShZg+hF94gBQi8mFBTa4gLI"
        appears:
               1 time(s) in /var/log/auth.log

Key 2
        label: "ansible key (RSA)"
        hash:  "SHA256:eedHBecrrsd8ESf4Ggl8S7my/p9YIhU77cvh/GrRxNY"
        does not appear.

Key 3
        label: "jim@jimsdesk (RSA)"
        hash:  "SHA256:cTQi5zMvfYegFAzffkWngraE8B1lJCagOxrS+TkwSaA"
        appears:
               4 time(s) in /var/log/auth.log.1

Key 4
        label: "root@w541 (RSA)"
        hash:  "SHA256:YmiLC7LFQ+mSE3SHkXzbpFuWi0HbIpGCaIUYuR6rAiM"
        does not appear.

Key 5
        label: "root@thumb (RSA)"
        hash:  "SHA256:Db+9kBzpOKy1DlOGYQB60njQ4uXVHBAl1pgBQ0+E0pg"
        does not appear.

Key 6
        label: "nagios@nagios-host (RSA)"
        hash:  "SHA256:dQWTtyWfp0eRyj1/6PHTLOKGOzS0hlktfd9Rqpg6vng"
        appears:
             574 time(s) in /var/log/auth.log
            1650 time(s) in /var/log/auth.log.0
            1650 time(s) in /var/log/auth.log.1
            1650 time(s) in /var/log/auth.log.2
            1650 time(s) in /var/log/auth.log.3
            1650 time(s) in /var/log/auth.log.4
            1650 time(s) in /var/log/auth.log.5
            1650 time(s) in /var/log/auth.log.6

Key 7
        label: "root@mrtg-host (RSA)"
        hash:  "SHA256:XLH0tz28SacSrur0pAfE2TB7mU37cm2BEH9IB/D+dew"
        does not appear.

Key 8
        label: "jim@w541 (RSA)"
        hash:  "SHA256:CvsACdXgliEpeQtUriFW87vpMZEbO6V7znj/3bhmPwo"
        does not appear.
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed, comprehensive, educational answer. I with i could give a double upvote for your effort